# How to turn on .sass extensions in Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic2

I have set up a basic project and only .scss files are picked up. I would like to write my CSS with the .sass format. How can I turn that on?

Comment: Which version of Ionic2 are you using?

Comment: ionic version 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You can override the app script config files:
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts#overriding-config-files

In my package.json, I added the following:

```
"config": {
  "ionic_sass": "./config/sass.config.js"
}
```

I created the sass.config.js (copy from the github project) and added the sass extension:

```
includeFiles: [
  /\.(scss|sass)$/i
],
```

It's unfortunately impossible to update the watch config file, so I directly edited it in the node module:

Under @ionic/app-scripts/config/watch.config.js

Add the following .sass line below .scss:

```
'{{SRC}}/**/*.scss',
'{{SRC}}/**/*.sass'
```